# pandas how to prevent expanding any specific column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

my original defame look like this:

```
index category      title         price      weight   description
 0    Men-Shirt    Shive Cotton   25,45  250g,100gm   buy the best shirt....
```

after applying explode method my data frame look like this:

```
  index category      title         price      weight   description
 0    Men-Shirt    Shive Cotton        25        250g   buy the best shirt....
 1    Men-Shirt    Shive Cotton        45       100gm   buy the best shirt....
```

I want to prevent expanding only description column. how to do that? here is my code:

```
data['price']=data['price'].str.split(',')
data['weight']=data['weight'].str.split(',')
data = data.set_index(['index','category', 'title','description']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

I also tried to remove description from my set index list but still now my description column expanding. How to prevent expanding description column?

Answer (score 0):

It is the characteristic of `explode()` to produce duplicated entries for columns *not* exploded. Even you set other unrelated fields as index, you will end up having more than one row with the same index, which after reset_index, will produce duplicated entries for these columns also.

As a workaround, you can consider wiping duplicated entries from the specific column `description`, as follows:

```
data['description'] = data['description'].mask(data.duplicated(subset=['category', 'title','description']), '')
```

Or, if `index` is a column instead of the dataframe row index, you can also include it in the subset of columns for checking duplicated entries:

```
data['description'] = data['description'].mask(data.duplicated(subset=['index', 'category', 'title','description']), '')
```

Here, we use [`.duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to check for duplicated entries, keeping only the first entry.  Then, use [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) on column `description` to check for rows duplicated and set these duplicated entries as empty strings.

**Result:**

```
print(data)


   index   category         title             description price weight
0      0  Men-Shirt  Shive Cotton  buy the best shirt....    25   250g
1      0  Men-Shirt  Shive Cotton                            45  100gm
```